# Location of Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.dll

Tags: development, user-profile

I am working on a Feature in C# in VS2010 for a Sharepoint 2010 site.  The business logic requires working with user accounts, so we are using UserProfile and UserProfileManager.  Theoretically (I have found in several places) those should be located in the  `Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.dll` assembly.  I have no idea where to find this file, however.  I have a local install of SP Server for development purposes and accordingly have the remainder of the references for `Microsoft.Sharepoint` and its "children" assemblies `Search` and `Security` in `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI\`.  The appropriate UserProfiles DLL is not located in this directory.

Though I have found evidence they no longer contain the necessary object binaries, the MS Office Interop assemblies do not show up in my 'Add Reference' dialogue box.  Additionally I am unable to reinstall them because the PIA installer fails - presumably because they are already installed (I've worked on Office Interop projects in the past with success).

Does anyone have a hint on where these libraries can be found/downloaded?

Comment: what is your environment? SharePoint & Visual Studio -version & edition,  etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within Visual Studio 2010 - when you 'Add Reference' (right-click the 'References' node in your VS 2010 project), it should be listed under the 'SharePoint' tab (for dll references).

The dll is located here (in my default VS 2010 installation) -
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI\Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.dll

Comment: Are you sure you've got a SharePoint server installation and not SharePoint Foundation? That dll should be in ISAPI. The SharePoint tab in Add Reference is only available if you've installed the CKS toolkit (which you should)

Answer (score 1):

In MOSS 2007, you use the Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles namespace in Microsoft.Office.Server.dll to work with a user's profile. But in SharePoint Server 2010, you should use the Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles namespace in Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.dll (the same namespace but with a different assembly).

Should be in C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI provided you are running Office server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the root cause is but you can pull the DLL of the installation ISO.

On the enterprise DVD ISO you can find the DLL in the .CAB file **Global\Ppl\pplwfe.cab**.